# Concetenating arrays in a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Say I have a Python dictionary with 100's of keys. For each key, the dictionary holds a 2D array.

All these 2D arrays have the same number of rows. How can I concatenate these arrays efficiently in a final 2D array along the column axis?

Is it worth going through Pandas for this? If so, how?

E.g.

```
from collections import OrderedDict()
dct = OrderedDict()
for key in xrange(3):
    dct[key] = np.random.randint(3,size=(2,np.random.randint(10)))

# Print the dictionary:
> dict(dct)
{0: array([[1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0]]),
 1: array([[2, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]]),
 2: array([[2],
       [0]])}
```

The result of the concatenation should be:

```
 array([[1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) function is exactly what you want.

Since you have an unordered dict, but an implied order in the keys, you probably want this:

```
>>> dct
defaultdict(<built-in function array>, {0: array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2]]), 1: array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 2, 2]]), 2: array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1, 2]])})
>>> np.hstack(dct[k] for k in sorted(dct))
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]])
```

---

Now that you've changed the question to use `OrderedDict` instead of `defaultdict`, you already have the values in the right order, so you can of course just use `dct.values()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. This was good to know (in case I go with `defaultdict`)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)  can do it.

```
np.concatenate(dct.values(), axis= 1)
```

Comment: Will definitely think again before asking something that I can answer myself in 10 min ... Sorry about that.

Comment: Almost, but this will concatenate them in an arbitrary order, not in the order implied by the keys.

Comment: Anyway, as the `hstack` docs say, it's "Equivalent to `np.concatenate(tup, axis=1)`. The `concatenate` function is more general than `hstack`, in that you can stack on a dynamically-chosen axis; I think `hstack` is more readable when you're specifically thinking in terms of "columnwise" instead of "axis 1", but really, that's a minor quibble either way.

Comment: Anyway, sometimes going through the trouble of formulating a good question is all it takes to inspire you to find the answer. As long as it actually is a good question (which I think this one was), there's no problem with that.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. You are absolutely right. I found the process of spelling out questions extremely helpful, even though it is important that users don't take unnecessarily  the time of other experts from answering other questions where their help is most needed.